# Mysql Simple Query question

Tags: mysql

I wrote out this Mysql query, but return a lot of blank fields for the `customers_telephone` table
since it was never a required field. I would like to return some dummy data on my
query (without inserting it into the database) if the field is NULL. I know MySQL
uses if clauses but I think it's only for creating databases or ... ?

here's my stamp

```
SELECT orders.orders_id AS recipient_id, delivery_company, delivery_street_address, delivery_city, delivery_postcode, delivery_state, delivery_country, customers_telephone
FROM orders, orders_products
WHERE orders.orders_id = orders_products.orders_id
AND products_id = 416
ORDER BY `orders`.`orders_id` DESC
```

**UPDATE**

I tried doing this, but it still is not working, maybe I did it in the wrong place?

```
SELECT orders.orders_id AS recipient_id, delivery_company, delivery_street_address, delivery_city,  delivery_postcode, delivery_state, delivery_country, IFNULL(customers_telephone, 'no number') AS customers_number
FROM orders, orders_products
WHERE orders.orders_id = orders_products.orders_id
AND products_id = 416
ORDER BY `orders`.`orders_id` DESC
```

Returns

```
recipient_id    delivery_company    delivery_street_address     delivery_city       delivery_postcode   delivery_state  delivery_country    number
191743          This Chick Bakes    31-31 48th Ave #B           Long Island City    11101               NY              United States       917.848.6437
191724                              44 Miraflores Ave (studio)  San Rafael          94901               CA              United States    
191723                              397 South River Street      Wilkes-Barre        18702               PA              United States
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function to provide a value if the field is NULL:

```
IFNULL(customers_telephone, 'dummydata') AS customers_telephone
```

`IFNULL` is a non-standard MySQL extension. The standard way is to use the [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function for this purpose. `COALESCE` is also supported by MySQL, but it is slightly slower than `IFNULL`, though it probably won't matter here.

Comment: @ehime: Perhaps they are empty strings, or strings containing only whitespace or other invisible characters.

Comment: It does look like it's a white space, what are my options?

Comment: `IFNULL(NULLIF(TRIM(customers_telephone), ''), 'dummydata')`

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
SELECT COALESCE(customers_telephone, 'no number') FROM ...
```